# Spark RDD - avoiding shuffle - Does partitioning help to process huge files?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application with around 10 flat files each worth more than 200MM+ records in them. Business logic involves in joining all of them sequentially.

my environment:
1 master - 3 slaves (for testing i have assigned a 1GB memory to each node)

Most of the code just does the below for each join

```
 RDD1 = sc.textFile(file1).mapToPair(..)

 RDD2 = sc.textFile(file2).mapToPair(..) 

 join = RDD1.join(RDD2).map(peopleObject)
```

Any suggestion for tuning , like repartitioning, parallelize ..? if so, any best practices in coming up with good number for repartitioning?

with the current config the job takes more than an hour and i see the shuffle write for almost every file is > 3GB

Comment: files stored over hdfs? how many partitions do you have?

Comment: No . They are in aws s3 and haven't done any partitions yet might be spark internally is using default parallelism.

Comment: Can you do RDD1.partitions.size or run "RDD1.toDebugString" and see what is the number of partitions u have?

Comment: Note that using a specific partitioner on load can be beneficial if you know that you are going to use the same RDD many times for joins. So you pay the shuffle cost once and you save it later.

Comment: I will get the values for RDD1.partitions.size or run "RDD1.toDebugString" . I am using the RDD upstream multiple times, but i am not sure how to add a specific partitioner on load. can please you shed some light or example on that in spark java?

Answer (score 2):

If we are always joining one RDD (say rdd1) with all the others, the idea is to partition that RDD and then persist it.

Here is sudo-Scala implementation (can easily be converted to Python or Java):

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile(file1).mapToPair(..).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(200)).cache()
```

Up to here we have rdd1 to be hashed into 200 partitions. The first time it will get evaluated it will be persisted (cached).

Now let's read two more rdds and join them.

```
val rdd2 = sc.textFile(file2).mapToPair(..) 
val join1 = rdd1.join(rdd2).map(peopleObject)
val rdd3 = sc.textFile(file3).mapToPair(..) 
val join2 = rdd1.join(rdd3).map(peopleObject)
```

Note that for the remanning RDDs we do not partition them nor do we cache them.

Spark will see that rdd1 is already hashed partition and it will use the same partitions for all remaining joins. So rdd2 and rdd3 will shuffle their keys to the same locations where the keys of rdd1 are located.

To make it more clear, let's assume that we don't do the partition and we use the same code shown by the question; Each time we do a join both rdds will be shuffled. This means that if we have N joins to rdd1, the non partition version will shuffle rdd1 N times. The partitioned approach will shuffle rdd1 just once.

Comment: What do we gain by caching the first RDD?

Comment: When all its keys find their home, they stay there until you are done with all you joins.

Comment: `rdd1` will be materialized once, when the first join is called. It will be cached henceforth, but it also won't be subsequently used (as per the given code by the OP). We don't need the `rdd1` until the join is finished. I see you have presented a slightly different use case. OP wanted rdd1.join(rdd2)....join(rddN) IMO. Caching is undoubtedly useful with the code presented in your answer.

Comment: Wait, I thought the idea was to join all remaining RDDs to rdd1. Obviously if each rdd is to be used once, caching them makes no sense.

Comment: I tried the below  approaches and dont see an improvement in the performance. Again, it might be something to do with memory/code but looking for suggestions. My RDD1 (1GB) and RDD2(6GB), RDD3(6GB). Used **mapToPair.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(200))** on 3 data sets and cached RDD1. next joined RDD1 with RDD2 and results with RDD3. The only logic i have in my mapToPair is to assign values to my object. I am running on a spark standalone cluster with below ` --num-executors 30 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 24G`

Answer (score 2):

In practice, with large datasets (5, 100G+ each), I have seen that the join works best when you co-partition all the RDDs involved in a series of join before you start joining them.

```
RDD1 = sc.textFile(file1).mapToPair(..).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2048))

RDD2 = sc.textFile(file2).mapToPair(..).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2048)) 
.
.
.
RDDN = sc.textFile(fileN).mapToPair(..).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2048)) 

//start joins
```

`RDD1.join(RDD2)...join(RDDN)`

---

Side note:
I refer to this kind of a join as a tree join (each RDD used once). The rationale is presented in the following beautiful pic taken from the Spark-UI:

[image]

Comment: /@mario - Thanks for the brief explanation . Infact i have both the use cases sequentially join RDD1 with the other RDD's as well as join RDDn1 , RDDn2 and the results with RDD1. Looking at the examples provided, my understanding is that, performance is better when i partition all the RDD's as well as cache the primary RDD. let me know if i got this right.

Comment: @SpringStarter Please note that in the case presented above, caching is going to actually hurt, since you are wasting space on something that's not needed. However, for the other use case that you have mentioned, caching would indeed help.